# How to upload data to thingsSpaek using arduino and esp8266?

Tags: arduino, esp8266

I am using an arduino and an esp8266 wifi module to upload data to the things spaek site.I found this code on instructables site inorder to upload random data to the things speak site but it is giving erro on case 3.

here is the code

```
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>
#define DEBUG true
#define RX 2
#define TX 3

String HOST = "api.thingspeak.com";
String PORT = "80";
String AP = "AP NAME";
String PASS = "AP PASSWORD";


String API = "---------";
String field = "field1";

int countTrueCommand;
int countTimeCommand; 
boolean found = false; 
int valSensor = 1;

SoftwareSerial esp8266(RX,TX); 
void setup() {

Serial.begin(9600);
esp8266.begin(115200);

sendCommand("AT",5,"OK");
sendCommand("AT+CWMODE=1",5,"OK");
sendCommand("AT+CWJAP=""+ AP +"",""+ PASS +""",15,"OK");
countTrueCommand = 0;

}

void loop() {

String getData = "GET /update?api_key="+ API +"&"+ field 
+"="+String(valSensor);
switch(countTrueCommand) {

case 0: sendCommand("AT",5,"OK");break;
case 1: sendCommand("AT+RST",10,"invalid");break;
case 2: sendCommand("AT+CIPMUX=1",5,"OK"); break;
case 3: sendCommand("AT+CIPSTART=0,"TCP","+ HOST +","+ PORT,15,"OK"); 
break;
case 4: sendCommand("AT+CIPSEND=0," +String(getData.length()+4),4,">"); 
break;
case 5: esp8266.println(getData);delay(1500);countTrueCommand++; break;
case 6: sendCommand("AT+CIPCLOSE=0",5,"OK"); break;
case 7:

Serial.println(valSensor);
Serial.print(getData);
Serial.print(",");
Serial.println(getData.length());
valSensor = random(100000); // random value, change with sensor value if 
using sensor
countTrueCommand = 0;
delay(10000);
break;

}

}
void sendCommand(String command, int maxTime, char readReplay[]) {

Serial.print(countTrueCommand);
Serial.print(". at command => ");
Serial.print(command);
Serial.print(" ");
while(countTimeCommand < (maxTime*1))

 {

 esp8266.println(command);//at+cipsend
 if(esp8266.find(readReplay))//ok
 {

  found = true;
  break;

  }
  countTimeCommand++;

  }
  if(found == true)
  {

  Serial.println("OYI");

  countTrueCommand++;
  countTimeCommand = 0;

  }
  if(found == false)
   {

   Serial.println("Fail");
   countTrueCommand = 0;
   countTimeCommand = 0;

   }
   found = false;
```

}

i am getttina an error on case 3 as
**exit status 1
unable to find string literal operator 'operator""TCP'**
How do i resolve it?

Comment: Syntax highlighting should have given you a hint.

Comment: i could not resolve it?Hence i put up the question.

Answer (score 0):

That line is not correct, please replace it with this:

```
    sendCommand("AT+CIPSTART=0,\"TCP\",\""+ HOST +"\","+ PORT,15,"OK"); //Start connection as client
```